# How to pass string resource reference in string array in android

Tags: android, arrays

I want to pass in string resource value in string array but it doesn't take value in array. it will take null value

**Below is my code :**

```
prepaid = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_prepaid);
dth = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_dth);

public String[] addedRTHomeList(){
        String[] homeList = {prepaid,dth,"PostPaid","Utility Services","Complaint Entry","Complaint Status","Recharge Status",chat,"Topup Request","Redeem Discount","Private Bus Booking","ST Bus Booking","Hotel Booking","Flight Booking","Money Transfer","Settings","Reports","DTH Activation"};
        return homeList;
    }


for(int i = 0; i < ba.addedRTHomeList().length ; i++)
        {
            md = new MenuDetail();
            md.setMenuName(ba.addedRTHomeList()[i]);
            md.setImageId(ba.RTDrwableListThemeRed()[i]);

            RTmenuListRed.add(md);

            RTMenuThemeRed.put(ba.RTMenuCode()[i],RTmenuListRed);
        }
```

In for loop when i access 1st value of  addedRTHomeList array it take null value

Comment: Why you don't want to use <string-array> resource?

Comment: You cannot to this `homeList = {prepaid,dth}`  you can only combine using Array.combine

Comment: Thanx .. if possible please share example..

Comment: hey michael in my case ..one array value set after web service response  so i do not use string-array resource

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this you can create `<string-array>` in your `string.xml`. like,

```
<string-array name="your_array_name">
    <item>Element 1</item>
    <item>Element 2</item>
    <item>Element 3</item>
    <item>Element 4</item>
    .
    .
    .

</string-array>
```

after this you can get in Java as,

```
String[] mTestArray = = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.your_array_name);
```

this may helps your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use AarryList instead of simple array becasue arraylist have easy dynamic implementation.

When you create array you have tell him its length.

```
public String[] addedRTHomeList(){
        String[] homeList = {prepaid,dth,"PostPaid","Utility Services","Complaint Entry","Complaint Status","Recharge Status",chat,"Topup Request","Redeem Discount","Private Bus Booking","ST Bus Booking","Hotel Booking","Flight Booking","Money Transfer","Settings","Reports","DTH Activation"};
        return homeList;
    }
```

Like Above homeList is size of 17 you cant add value in 18 index because 18 is not exist that why you are getting this error

**Solution:**

Use String ArrayList example usage

```
ArrayList<String> homeList = new ArrayList<String>();

homeList.add("PostPaid");
homeList.add("Complaint Status");
homeList.add("Recharge Status");

.
.
}
```

to get Value from ArrayList `homeList.get(index)` Simply.

now if you add value it will create new index and add it on last.
Best Of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an exception because you are trying to initialize the variables as class variables. I moved the initialization inside `addedRTHomeList()` method and found no issues.

Try this code,

```
public String[] addedRTHomeList(){
    String prepaid = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_prepaid);
    String dth = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_dth);
    String chat = getResources().getString(R.string.lbl_chat);

    return new String[]{prepaid,dth,"PostPaid","Utility Services","Complaint Entry","Complaint Status","Recharge Status",chat,"Topup Request","Redeem Discount","Private Bus Booking","ST Bus Booking","Hotel Booking","Flight Booking","Money Transfer","Settings","Reports","DTH Activation"};
}

String[] items = ba.addedRTHomeList();
for(int i = 0; i < items.length ; i++){
    md = new MenuDetail();
    md.setMenuName(items[i]);
    md.setImageId(ba.RTDrwableListThemeRed()[i]);

    RTmenuListRed.add(md);

    RTMenuThemeRed.put(ba.RTMenuCode()[i],RTmenuListRed);
}
```

Comment: all that value which have refernce like prepaid,dth,chat